# IIS 8 Configure sub-web application not to use form login of the parent application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a website that is configured in IIS 8 with forms authentication. In IIS, this site has a sub-application which hosts a simple ASMX web service. When I attempt to view or call the web service, it is being redirected to the login page of the parent application (which is not what I want).

I've tried using location elements in my web.config as I've seen suggested for similar questions such as this one ([How to bypass forced login for a token authenticating service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686889/how-to-bypass-forced-login-for-a-token-authenticating-service))
but it has not been successful.

I'm trying to access the web service via url like this: http://mysite.mydomain.com/Webservices/myservice.asmx

So I attempted to configure my location element like this:

```
<location path="Webservices">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

However, after implementing this in my parent application's web.config, calls to http://mysite.mydomain.com/Webservices/myservice.asmx will still redirect to a login page.

Is there something I'm missing? Is this accomplished differently in IIS8?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see if it helps get you on the right path...
[Configuring subdirectory authentication mode in applications hosted under root site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356638/configuring-subdirectory-authentication-mode-in-applications-hosted-under-root-s)